# How can I listen to an archived voicemail that has been saved in internal storage/music?

Tags: samsung, internal-storage, voicemail

My phone is a Samsung Galaxy A20. I have several archived voicemail messages that I am trying to listen to, but when I try to retrieve them, a message pops up that reads, "Unable to play music. This music format is not supported". It shows the path as:
`/Internal storage/Music/Samsung Messages/Voice message` (along with various details specific to each message such as the other person's phone number)

I am a novice and therefore I don't understand what this means. I would just like to know how or if I can even listen to these messages in order to find the ones that I am looking for and erase those that are no longer needed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome Renee! Fret not, you're in the right place! It may help yield answers if you add the model of your device to your question.

Comment: What app(s) have you tried for playback?

Comment: @Robert I have only tried listening to it on my phone. Unfortunately, I'm not sure what apps to try or any other options that I have for playback. I could not find anything online anywhere regarding this problem so any suggestions for apps to try would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: @EndAnti-SemiticHate Thank you, I added the model of my phone to the post. I know it's an old phone but I don't use it enough to justify buying a new one. I'm familiar with this one and for the most part, I've been able to figure out or fix problems along the way.

Comment: Thanks for adding it.  Nothing wrong with an old phone if it meets your needs.  I'm not an expert on the A20, but I think it's known as a very good phone for the price.  And, honestly, it's not very old at all.